# Extract sentences that contain certain words using Regex

Tags: python, regex

Say I have the following string :

```
txt = 'the car is running, the car has wheels, wheels are round, the road is clear, wheels make the car go'
```

What I'm trying to do is get all sentences (that is between commas) that have either 'car' or 'wheels' in them. Using regex, I did the following :

```
re.findall('[^,]*{}|{}[^,]*'.format('car', 'wheels'), txt)
```

And I get this result :

```
['the car', ' the car', 'wheels', 'wheels are round', ' wheels make the car']
```

Apparently, it only gives back what's between the words 'car' and 'wheels', and it seems like the order matters.
What I'm trying to get is this :

```
['the car is running', 'the car has wheels', 'wheels are round', 'wheels make the car go']
```

Any ideas about how to do this ?

Comment: please give your wanted output

Comment: I just added it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex of

```
re.findall('[^,]*{}|{}[^,]*'.format('car', 'wheels'), txt)
```

only needs small a modificiation, the inclusion of a (non-capturing) group, otherwise the `|` applies to the entire regex, as opposed to just the `car|wheels`.

Your new regex will be

```
re.findall('[^,]*(?:{}|{})[^,]*'.format('car', 'wheels'), txt)
```

This outputs:

```
['the car is running', ' the car has wheels', ' wheels are round', ' wheels make the car go']
```

However, I don't think regex is suitable for this problem. I would advise the following solution instead:

```
txt = 'the car is running, the car has wheels, wheels are round, the road is clear, wheels make the car go'
# Either:
sentences = [sentence.strip() for sentence in txt.split(",") if "car" in sentence or "wheels" in sentence]
# Or alternatively:
words = ["car", "wheels"]
sentences = [
    sentence.strip() # Remove spaces before and after the sentence
    for sentence in txt.split(",")
    if any(
        word in sentence
        for word in words
    )
]
# This second method allows for checking for more than just 2 words
```

This outputs:

```
['the car is running', 'the car has wheels', 'wheels are round', 'wheels make the car go']
```

---

### Performance

The performance of the two methods (list comprehension and regex) can be compared with the following script, which runs the code in the strings 100 times, for a text with 40k sentences.

```
import timeit
import re

# Set up a testing text with 40k sentences.
txt = (
    "the car is running, the car has wheels, wheels are round, the road is clear, "
    * 10000
)

# The (simple) list comprehension strategy
list_comp_time = timeit.timeit(
    '[sentence for sentence in txt.split(",") if "car" in sentence or "wheels" in sentence]',
    globals=globals(),
    number=100,
)

# A strategy using regex
regex_time = timeit.timeit(
    "re.findall('[^,]*(?:{}|{})[^,]*'.format('car', 'wheels'), txt)",
    globals=globals(),
    number=100,
)

print(f"The List Comprehension method took {list_comp_time:.8f}s")
print(f"The Regex method took {regex_time:.8f}s")
```

The output is:

```
The List Comprehension method took 0.48497320s
The Regex method took 3.71355870s
```

With other words, the List Comprehension method is more time-efficient.

Comment: Isn't this approach going to take more time compared to regex ? I'm doing this on a large data set and I'm afraid that creating and manipulating lists this way might be a bit slow

Comment: It will not. Regex is not particularly time-efficient as compared to simple list comprehensions. See my last edit for more information.

Comment: Yes, this clears things out for me, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

This approach can help but without any usage of `regex`:

```
txt = 'the car is running, the car has wheels, wheels are round, the road is clear, wheels make the car go'

result = [ x for x in txt.split(',') if "car" in x or "wheel" in x]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['the car is running', ' the car has wheels', ' wheels are round', ' wheels make the car go']
```

Comment: Use `any(…)`, otherwise +1.

Comment: The problem is I'm doing this on a large data set, I'm worried that this approach might take a while compared to regex

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re

txt = 'the car is running, the car has wheels, wheels are round, the road is clear, wheels make the car go'

print(re.findall(r"(?<!,)[^,]*(?:car|wheels)[^,]*", txt))
```

Output:

```
['the car is running', 'the car has wheels', 'wheels are round', 'wheels make the car go']
```

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
txt = 'the car is running, the car has wheels, wheels are round, the road is clear, wheels make the car go'
b = [a for a in txt.split(',') if re.findall(r'car|wheels', a)]
print(b)
```

Comment: This seems to work just fine thank you, but is it faster than regex ?